# primary product, secondary product, next?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What follows after the words primary and secondary?
What's the English word for it (meaning 3rd basically)?

Comment: Closing may seem a bit harsh, but if I search for "What comes after primary secondary" then the first result is an [Oxford Dictionaries reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-comes-after-primary-secondary-tertiary) which carries on up to ten.

Comment: The Wiktionary entry on [primary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/primary) straight out links to secondary, tertiary, and quaternary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tertiary is the word you're looking for.